# CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed

Tags: azure-synapse, polybase

When creating an external table, I get the below error:

> Msg 105005, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'wasbs://.blob.core.windows.net/folder/Reject_Directory/_rejectedrows/' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.

I'm trying to create an external table using polybase, removing the `REJECTED_ROW_LOCATION` option works fine, but including it causes this error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else had already created the `Reject_Directory/_rejectedrows` folder, for some reason this caused a permissions error.

Delete the `Reject_Directory/_rejectedrows` folder from the blob store, so that Polybase can create it itself and the table can now be created.

Answer (score 0):

Please check on below two things.
I was able to resolve this error by checking/adding the following things.

1. Make sure when you create credentials -> you add enough permissions while generating the tokens. This will help to create/loan the error records file in the ADLS container.
2. Make sure you use this with TYPE=HADOOP.
   For that -> CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE name WITH (
   LOCATION='location', CREDENTIAL = credential name, TYPE=HADOOP).
   and then try adding REJECT_ROW_LOCATION while creating EXTERNAL TABLE.